# Postgresql update column from one table to another

Tags: postgresql

How do i update inventory_id in TABLE2 from TABLE1 inventory_id?

So far I've tried

```
UPDATE TABLE2
SET 
inventory_id=t1.inventory_id
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN
TABLE1 t1
ON t1.test_id = t2.test_id
WHERE t1.test_id = t2.test_id;
```

But this sets all the value of inventory_id in TABLE2 as 1 instead of my expected result.

```
TABLE1
inventory_id     test_id
1                         26
2                         56
3                         12
4                         67
```

```
TABLE2
test_id       inventory_id
12
26
56
67
```

Such that it becomes like this?

```
TABLE2
test_id       inventory_id
12              3
26              1
56              2
67              4
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: @stickybit sorry about that. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation on `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) states:

> ```
> UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
> ...
>     [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> `from_item`
>
> A table expression allowing columns from other tables to appear in the
> `WHERE` condition and update expressions. This uses the same syntax as
> the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement; for example, an alias for
> the table name can be specified. **Do not repeat the target table as a
> `from_item` unless you intend a self-join** (in which case it must appear with an alias in the `from_item`).

(emphasis: me)

So following that you want:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
       SET inventory_id = t1.inventory_id
       FROM table1 t1
            WHERE t1.test_id = t2.test_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=302d30c03d90ff037c8e5cb8f66549c5)

You pretty much had it but seem to got confused by the syntax you may have seen for other DBMS and mixed them.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the PostgreSQL UPDATE JOIN syntax should give:

```
UPDATE TABLE2 t2
SET 
t2.inventory_id=t1.inventory_id
FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.test_id = t2.test_id;
```